# navigator.mediaDevicesenumerateDevice() "audiooutput" not show in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, getusermedia, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

I found a problem that `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevice()` not show a `audiooutput` when I use **Safari** browser [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN3KV.jpg) but `audioinput` and `videoinput` still normally

In another case I use **Chrome** browser to see `audiooutput` but it can show `audiooutput` normally in log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvHMU.jpg)

did anyone know why `audiooutput` can not show in **Safari** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari's getUserMedia() implementation is incomplete: it doesn't show output devices. Sad but true.